# Linking Map in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using RN 0.20 for iOS. I want to make a link where if you click that link, it will redirect you to the Map apps available in the phone with its coordinate. This is what I have done using Linking component.

```
redirectToMap() {
    Linking.canOpenURL('geo:37.484847,-122.148386').then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL('geo:37.484847,-122.148386');
        } else {
            console.log('Don\'t know how to go');
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

But it keeps giving me 'Don't know how to go'. However, I see from its documentation in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html that it is doable to use `geo:` to link to map.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Use correct URL scheme

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) of iOS.
To open maps, use the suggested scheme:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lat>,<long>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: OK, but why linking with `geo` URL doesn't work? As @KelvinAliyanto mentioned, it's clearly written in React Native documentation. I expected, that when I use `geo` URL a menu pops up (if there are more than 1 map application), something like this: http://www.kevinandamanda.com/whatsnew/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Create-a-Custom-Travel-Map-with-Google-Maps-New-My-Maps-Tutorial-29-406x720.jpg

Comment: Follow the link to the official documentation of iOS. It says: "Unlike some schemes, map URLs do not start with a “maps” scheme identifier. Instead, map links are specified as regular http links and are opened either in Safari or the Maps app on the target platform."

Comment: If you want to start a navigation, use `http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=<lat>,<long>`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use react-native-open-maps package

1. Install the repository
   `$ npm install --save react-native-open-maps`
2. Add an import to the top of your file
   `import openMap from 'react-native-open-maps'`
3. Put it all together

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import openMap from 'react-native-open-maps'

export default class App extends Component {
  _goToYosemite() {
    openMap({ latitude: 37.865101, longitude: -119.538330 });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Button
        color={'#bdc3c7'}
        onPress={this._goToYosemite}
        title="Click To Open Maps " />
    );
  }
}
```